# AWS firehose delievery stream with lambda function with putrecord

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using Kinesis firehose delivery stream. I am putting the record into the delivery stream using PutRecord API. One observation putRecord takes the Record as an argument and internally it take byteBuffer.

I am able to successfully put the record in firehose delivery stream. Now I m having lambda function implemented in nodejs to do the transformation over the records in kinesis firehose stream.

In my lambda function i am getting the bytestream instead of string in my lambda function. Any idea why this happening ? I tried converting byte stream into string but no luck

Answer (score 0):

from AWS doc I came to know that data is posted to lambda function is BASE64 encoded We need to decode the data.

Thanks